# Weird searching results in Safari 8.0.2

Tags: macos, safari, search

I kept having some bizarre search results return, and I just noticed when I type something into the Safari omnibar, it's trying to search on the register.co.uk.

My default search engine is set to Google:

[image: default]

However, those results seem to be down below.

[image: register]

My first round of results are being sent to The Register.

I've been all through my settings and my preferences, I can't see anything which says to **also** search on The Register.

Is anyone else running into this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is the quick website search feature. You can disable it or remove the website: [Link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27448902#27448902)

Comment: Please quote the relevant points from the page you're linking to in order to prevent link-rot.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Safari's Quick Website search takes your first word as a hint about which website you want to search. Unfortunately, The Register's site starts, of course, with the very common word "the", so if you start any search with "the", whether it's "the gambler" or "The Three Musketeers", it'll trigger a The Register search. Disable The Register in Preferences/Search/Manage Websites.